# Difference between different implementations assigned to broader type in Java

Tags: java, list, set

I know that its considered best practice to assign subclass implementations to variables of an Interface type in order to maintain flexibility like so:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

My current understanding is that when declaring `list` as type `List`, you limit its functionality to only implementations of methods that type `List` requires, and doesn't allow implementation-specific methods. That said, what's the difference between:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Other than some obvious performance differences caused by the different implementations of each class for the List interface, are there any differences?

As another example, using `Set`, I know that doing:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
```

gives you a `HashSet` as a `Set`, whereas:

```
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
```

gives you a `TreeSet` as a `Set` which means (among other things), that `set` is automatically sorted. But isn't the automatic sorting an implementation-specific function of the class?

Comment: `TreeSet` is also a [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) (among other things).

Comment: This I know, but the interface that this is being declared as is `Set`, which is not a `SortedSet`, so why then is it automatically sorted as a `Set`?

Comment: `List` and `Set` don't impose any ordering... implementations are free to do any ordering they please.

Comment: Yes, but, wouldn't the sorting that is implemented by the subclasses require implementation-specific methods that are not available from the `Set` interface? To my understanding, when you declare an object as an interface and use a subclass constructor, then you are limiting the object to containing only the methods that the interface requires. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Powerlord: `List` keeps order. A `List` implementation is not free to reorder the items, that would break the `List` contract. (first words of the doc: `An ordered collection`)

Comment: @NathanRobb as a user, you can only access the methods that are defined by the interface. However, the method you call are actually implemented by the concrete types, which behaves as they please. When calling a method of `List` on a variable that has declared type `List` and assigned type `ArrayList`, the result is the same as if the declared type was `ArrayList`.

Comment: Unless, perhaps, when you declare an object as an interface and use a subclass constructor, then the object still HAS the implementation-specific, but calling them from outside the class would cause a compile-time error because the object must be treated as an object of the baseclass when outside the subclass because that's how its been declared... Is this correct?

Comment: For example, `List` is also `Iterable`. You could declare `Iterable<String> iter = new ArrayList<>();`. But then, even though `iter` is actually an `ArrayList`, you could not call the `add` method on it, because the declared type `Iterable` does not know that method.

Comment: Using the example you provided @njzk2, the iter object itself would still be able to access its own methods, just not the user?

Comment: Later you could redefine `iter` as `iter = new HashSet<>();` which is valid because `Set` extends `Iterable`, but you can see now that `Set` and `List` have difference methods, so it wouldn't make sense to call specific methods from `Set` or `List` on a variable that is declared as `Iterable`

Comment: So the iter object would still be able to access the add() method, only the user cannot because the user sees the object as type `Iterable`... correct?

Comment: Sure. `Iterable` is an interface, in itself it does not know what to do when you call `iterator()` on it. The actual implementation is in the concrete type, `ArrayList` for example. In this case, here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.iterator%28%29

Comment: Absolutely. the user can only see the methods of the type it *declares* (the left-hand class name)

Comment: @njzk2 Yeah, sorry, it's `Collection` and `Set` that don't impose ordering.

Comment: So the iter object is still an `ArrayList` object, but the user sees it as an `Iterable` object which doesn't have all of the `ArrayList` methods....

Comment: ** MIND BLOWN ** Thank you. Would you mind posting this answer in detail for others in my position? Thank you so much for clarifying that for me.

Comment: If you're declaring a variable by its interface, you only have access to the methods that interface defines.  However, the other major thing is that there may be different performance characteristics involved.  `TreeSet`, for example, has `O(log n)` performance for its add method, while `HashSet` and `LinkedHashSet` have `O(1)` performance.  `HashSet` is randomly ordered, `LinkedHashSet` is ordered by insertion order, and `TreeSet` is ordered by the `Comparable` for the objects or `Comparator` specified in the constructor.

Comment: @NathanRobb I would, but the question is closed, so no answer can be added. I voted to reopen, so it might be, but until then there is nothing much we can do.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. For those who are reading this post, the answer is that the user of the class doesn't have access to any methods that aren't present in the interface that the object is declared as, but the *object itself* does.

Answer (score 0):

As already correctly stated in the comments, if you are declaring a variable by its interface, you only have access to the methods defined by that interface. The main difference between the concrete types resides in the performance of the implementation.

**But** some method defined in the interface are also optionally implemented. For example the method `add`of the [`java.util.Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface throws an [`UnsupportedOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html), if the add operation is not supported by the concrete type that implents the `Set` interface.